# React Disable a Button Until Another is Pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-native

I have a submit button that I want to disable until a rating has been placed.

Initial State

```
this.state = {
      stars: [
        { active: false },
        { active: false },
        { active: false },
        { active: false },
        { active: false }
      ]
    };
```

Function for onChange

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({stars: e.target.value})
  }
```

Here is my code for my button of a typical 5 star rating

```
<View style={styles.feedBackBtn}>
                {this.state.stars.map((item, index) =>
                  <Button
                    transparent
                    key={index}
                    onPress={() => this.rate(index)}>
                    value={this.state.stars}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  </Button>
                )}
 </View>
```

Here is my submit button

```
<View style={styles.slideSelector}>
            <Button style={{ flex: 1}} block large
              onPress={() => this.goBack()}
              disabled={!this.state.stars}>
              <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, 
              fontWeight:"700" }}>SUBMIT</Text>
            </Button>
</View>
```

I don't think the onChange works for buttons as it is not an input. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that far simple way,

There is no need to create array of active state , you can do it like

> Setting state :

```
this.state = {
    stars: -1, // this will show star's selected index
    star_length : 5 // star's length
};
```

> Your Function :

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({stars: e.target.value}) // set the index which is clicked
}
```

> Rendering part :

```
<View style={styles.feedBackBtn}>
    {
        // you can use this also Array.apply(null, Array(this.state.star_length)).map(...)
        [...Array(this.state.star_length)].map((x, i) => // loop through the length of array
            <Button
            transparent
            key={i}
            onPress={() => this.rate(i)}>
            value={i <= this.state.stars}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            </Button>
        )}
    }
 </View>

 <View style={styles.slideSelector}>
    <Button style={{ flex: 1}} block large
        onPress={() => this.goBack()}
        disabled={this.state.stars === -1}> // just compare with selected index
        <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, 
        fontWeight:"700" }}>SUBMIT</Text>
    </Button>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.stars` will always be defined. What I would do is the following:

**Initial State**

```
this.state = {
  stars: [
    { active: false },
    { active: false },
    { active: false },
    { active: false },
    { active: false }
  ],
  hasRating: false
};
```

**Function for onChange**

```
handleChange(e) {
   this.setState({stars: e.target.value, hasRating: true})
}
```

**Here is my submit button, if you want to disable**

```
<View style={styles.slideSelector}>
            <Button style={{ flex: 1}} block large
              onPress={() => this.goBack()}
              disabled={this.state.hasRating}>
              <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, 
              fontWeight:"700" }}>SUBMIT</Text>
            </Button>
</View>
```

**Here is my submit button, if you want to hide**

```
{this.state.hasRating &&
    <View style={styles.slideSelector}>
        <Button style={{ flex: 1}} block large
              onPress={() => this.goBack()}
        >
              <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, 
              fontWeight:"700" }}>SUBMIT</Text>
        </Button>
</View>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original function is completely changing the `stars` property to just one boolean value. Instead you need to pass in the star that was actually changed:

```
handleChange(e, index) {
  const stars = ...this.state.stars
  stars[index]['active'] = !stars[index]['active'];

  this.setState({ stars })
}
```

And pass in the index via `bind()`. You get the `index` from your `map()` :

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, index)}
```

As far as disabling the button you'll just need to see if at least one of the stars is active using `some()`:

```
disabled={this.state.stars.some(star => star)}
```